# Nonlinear systems of ordinary differential equations

Tags: numerical-methods, differential-equations

Is it possible to solve for a system's initial state given final state and a system of nonlinear differential equations describing the rates of change of various aspects of the system?

For example:

```
V_x' = n * cos(b)
V_y' = (n * sin(b)) - (g_0 * (r_0 / r)^2)
b' = ((g_0 * (r_0 / r)^2) * cos(b)) / ||V||

b_final = 0
V_y_final = 0
V_x_final = √((G×M)/r^2)
```

- `V_x` is horizontal speed
- `V_y` is vertical speed
- `b` is the angle above the horizon
- `n` is the thrust/weight ratio
- `r_0` is the radius of the planet

Comment: This sounds more appropriate for [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Are you sure that this is the complete system? To get the correct `r(t)` you would also need the position, and then you probably will impose conditions on starting on the planet surface. The problem then becomes a **boundary value problem (BVP)**. If you also include a target height then you need to make the time interval variable, which again can be transformed into a BVP.

Comment: Hmmm...Ok, so r'(t) is vertical speed, which equals v * sin(beta) <i think...> The target height is, say, 200 km. the planet is 3,840 km in radius, and g_0 = 9.81 m/s2

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is as easy as integrating forward. In fact, for `y'=f(t,y)` on `t in [t0,tf]` with `y(tf)=yf` given, you can

1. ) formally change the time direction by considering `z(s)=y(tf-s)` which then satisfies the differential equation `z'(s)=-f(tf-s,z(s))`, or
2. ) employ a negative step size, which in most standard integrators can be achieved by passing the list of sampling times in descending order, like `T, Z = ode45(odefunc, [tf, t0], yf)`. The only restriction I found in documentations is that the time list has to be all in one direction, no reversals inside the list.

Comment: Hmmm... Can you share an example of Python code that does this?